# Android - Divide the screen into layouts programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to divide the screen, programmatically, this way:

```
|-------------|
|             |
|             |
|             |
|--|----------|
|  |          |
|--|----------|
```

What I have is one main LinearLayout, which inside have two LinearLayouts, one is topLL, with weight of 1, and one is bottomLL, with weight of 5.

inside bottomLL there are also two LinearLayouts, on bottomLeftLL with weight of 5, and one bottomRightLL with weight of 50.

The actual result is actually almost right, it's this:

```
|-------------|
|             |
|             |
|             |
|------|------|
|      |      |
|------|------|
```

Top and bottom are correctly divided but bottomLeft and bottomRight get the same portion of the bottom part instead of the weights I've mentioned.

Any idea why? EDIT: here's the relevant code:

```
        main = new LinearLayout(....);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        main.setLayoutParams(mainLayoutParams);
        main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        main.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        main.setVerticalGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout mainTop = new LinearLayout(....);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainTopLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mainTopLayoutParams.weight = 1;
        mainTop.setLayoutParams(mainTopLayoutParams);
        mainTop.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        mainTop.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        mainTop.setVerticalGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout mainBottom = new LinearLayout(...);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainBottomLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mainBottomLayoutParams.weight = 5;
        mainBottom.setLayoutParams(mainBottomLayoutParams);
        //mainBottom.setWeightSum(55); - it was suggested but didn't work
        mainBottom.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        mainBottom.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        mainBottom.setVerticalGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout mainBottomLeft = new LinearLayout(...);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainBottomLeftLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mainBottomLeftLayoutParams.weight = 50;
        mainBottomLeft.setLayoutParams(mainBottomLeftLayoutParams);
        mainBottomLeft.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        mainBottomLeft.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.END);
        mainBottomLeft.setVerticalGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout mainBottomRight = new LinearLayout(...);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainBottomRightLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mainBottomRightLayoutParams.weight = 5;
        mainBottomRight.setLayoutParams(mainBottomLeftLayoutParams);
        mainBottomRight.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        mainBottomRight.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.START);
        mainBottomRight.setVerticalGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the "weights" of each of the lower left and lower right parts programmatically by applying LayoutParams to those views.

Assuming you already have a reference to both those bottom parts:

```
LinearLayout llBottomLeft = (LinearLayout) findViewById(....;
LinearLayout llBottomRight = ....;

LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParam1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5.0f);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParam2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50.0f);

llBottomLeft.setLayoutParams(llParam1);
llBottomRight.setLayoutParams(llParam2);
```

Remember to also put a "weightSum" param to their common parent with a value of "55":

`llBottomContainer.setWeightSum(55.0f);`

Comment: It didn't work :( I think it'll be better if I supply some code, see my edit soon

Comment: In your sample code I didn't saw where you are actually applying the new layout params to the actual left and right LinearLayouts, so the `llBottomLeft.setLayoutParams(llParam1)` part.

Comment: I'm doing  mainBottomLayoutParams.weight = 5; instead

Comment: Damn it! it was eventually a copy-paste problem in my code. Thanks anyone to all helpers :)

Comment: `I'm doing mainBottomLayoutParams.weight = 5; instead` This is fine, but after setting some weight to a LayoutParams object, you also need to set the resulting LayoutParams object as the current LayoutParams of the LinearLayout, hence the `ll.setLayoutParams()`.